# splitting url causing firefox to bug

Tags: javascript, url, split

I am trying ot implement the passing of variables with get between formulars and I basically use the `split()` method to recover the variable on each page. The problem that I have is that the script is stopped when I implement the splitting.

It wasn't doing so earlier and now that I added the second function to check all the values of all the input names, I get this problem. I am new to javacsript so I don't really know where to look for and on top of this I really need to be able to get the variable's value.
Here are the html of the first form and of the second one, with the `url.split("?");` causing firefox and my computer to get lost in the process...

Here the first page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow" />
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

// -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Choose between<br />
<form name="fo" method="get" action="part1.html">
<input type="radio" name="s1" value="1" />one<br />
<input type="radio" name="s2" value="2" />two<br />
<input type="radio" name="s3" value="3" />three<br />
<input type="submit" value="continuer" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here the part1.html page, that contains the buggy script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function gValue(varname) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var qparts = url.split("?");

    if (qparts.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    var query = qparts[1];
    var vars = query.split("&");
    var value = "";

        for (i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
            var parts = vars[i].split("=");
            if (parts[0] == varname) {
                value = parts[1];
                break;
            }
        }
    return value;
}

function subnewsc() {
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {
        var schck = "s" + i;
        var score = gValue(schck);
        score = parseInt(score);
        i = parseInt(i);
        var newscore = score+i;
        var doc = "document.fo.s" + i;
        doc.value=newscore;
    }
}
// -->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="subnewsc();">
<div>choose between<br />
<form name="fo" method="get" action="part2.html">
<input type="radio" name="s1" value="1" />one again<br />
<input type="radio" name="s2" value="2" />two again<br />
<input type="radio" name="s3" value="3" />three again<br />
<input type="submit" value="continuer" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the loop iterator in other loop, causing infinite loop.

Change this line:

```
for (i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
```

To this:

```
for (var i=0; i<vars.length; i++) {
```

And you won't get into infinite loop.

Some explanation is required.. in the function `subnewsc` you have loop, using `i` as the loop iterator. As you don't have `var` before, it's becoming global variable. Now inside that loop you call the function `gValue` where you also have loop, again using `i` as the loop iterator and without the `var` it means using **the same variable** as in the first loop. This of course is causing havoc.

For example, when you read the value of second querystring item, `i` will have value of 1 after you call `var score = gValue(schck);` so it will never get more than 3.

By adding the `var` keyword you'll make the variable have local scope and solve all this mess.

Comment: thank you very much, solved the problem with a clear explanation

Comment: thank YOU for your precious answers and for your advice on how to contribute into the community